# C++ concurrent outstream

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, parallel-processing, mutex

I wrote a little class using `boost` and `std::stringstream` to provide concurrent `std::ostream` support. The class needs to know the number of threads in advance (even though this behavior could be adjusted) and the class uses the concept of channels to identify the different threads in order to minimize resource concurrency, to output whole blocks and avoid blocking, the class buffers input for each thread in a `stringstream` object. When the thread calls flush(), the buffer is flushed, if the `ostream` resource is not busy or if the buffer is full.

Do you see any (performance) problems with this implementation? Especially, using channels I tried to limit the number of `stringstream` object constructions. Is there a good way to tell the `stringstream` objects the length of the string to allocate? Would it be worth to use char arrays for buffering instead? I chose `stringstream` not only for its easy usage but also for the fact, that I achieve full `ostream` compatibility in the ()-operator member function.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include<ostream>
#include<sstream>

class ConcurrentOutStream {
  public:
    ConcurrentOutStream( std::ostream& os, const uint channels, const uint buffer_size ) :
      os_( os ),
      max_buffer_size_( buffer_size ),
      buffers_( channels )
      {
        for ( uint i=0; i<threads; ++i ) buffers_.push_back( new std::ostringstream ); //because streams are not copyable
      };

    ~ConcurrentOutStream() {
      for ( uint i=0; i<buffers_.size(); ++i ) forceFlush( i );
    }

    std::ostream& operator()( const uint channel ) { return buffers_[channel]; }

    void flush( const uint channel ) {
      if ( buffers_[channel].str().size() < max_buffer_size_ ) tryFlush( channel );
      else forceFlush( channel );
    }

    const uint channels() { return buffers_.size(); };

  protected:
    void tryFlush( const uint channel ) { // write if ostream not busy
      if ( mutex_.try_lock() ) {
        os_ << buffers_[channel].str();
        buffers_[channel].str("");
        mutex_.unlock();
      }
    }

    void forceFlush( const uint channel ) {
      if ( ! buffers_[channel].str().empty() ) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock( mutex_ );
        os_ << buffers_[channel].str();
        buffers_[channel].str("");
      }
    }

    std::ostream& os_;
    const uint max_buffer_size_;
    boost::ptr_vector< std::ostringstream > buffers_;
    boost::mutex mutex_;
};
```